# Why is this ternary operator invalid in JS

Tags: javascript

```
​var truth = true;
(truth) ? console.log('It is true') : throw new Error('It is not true');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Do ternary operators only accept specific types of objects?

Comment: You could make a function: `function _throw(msg) { throw new Error(msg); }` then use it in the conditional operator: `truth ? console.log("true") : _throw("It is not true");`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

javascript distinguishes between statements and expressions.  The ternary operator only handles expressions; throw is a statement.

Answer (score 4):

It does work, but the problem is the throw statement in your "else" branch.

Use

```
(truth) ? console.log('It is true') : (function(){throw 'It is not true'}());
```

Comment: This makes @Freddie code works but does not explain that ternary need to be an expression and not a statement.

Answer (score 2):

The conditional operator, like all other operators, can only be used with expressions.

`throw x;` is a *statement*, not an expression.